# airflow task depend on another task result?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have 2 tasks

the first task download some datasets to `folder_1`

the second task cleaning every file on `folder_1`

`CRUDE_NEW_DATASET_LOCAL` is a local path

```
download_crude_new_dataset = BashOperator(
        task_id = "download_crude_new_dataset",
        bash_command = bash.download_crude_new_dataset(),
        dag=dag
)

cleaning_crude_new_dataset = []
crude_new_dataset = glob(bash.CRUDE_NEW_DATASET_LOCAL+"/*",recursive=True)
for p in crude_new_dataset :
    path = p.replace('\\','/')
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        cleaning_crude_new_dataset.append(
            BashOperator(
                task_id = "cleaning_crude_new_dataset-"+bash._path_leaf_(path),
                bash_command = bash.cleaning_dataset(path),
                dag=dag
            )
    ) 

download_crude_new_dataset >> cleaning_crude_new_dataset
```

the problem while i trigger the airflow dag, the `folder_1` still empty. and that make `cleaning_crude_new_dataset` (array of task) are empty.

thanks for helping

Comment: Please write the entire DAG.

Comment: code was edited @MeghdeepRay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was solved

split the task from single Dag into multiple Dags
and trigger other dags (`dag1` >> `dag2` >> `dag3` ... )

if need, change the `dag_dir_list_interval` from 300 to small number

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
download_crude_new_dataset = BashOperator(
        task_id= "download_crude_new_dataset",
        bash_command= bash.download_crude_new_dataset(),
        dag= dag
)

#cleaning_crude_new_dataset = []

crude_new_dataset = glob( bash.CRUDE_NEW_DATASET_LOCAL + "/*", recursive= True )
for p in crude_new_dataset :
    path = p.replace( '\\', '/' )
    if os.path.isfile( path ):
        temp_task = BashOperator(
            task_id= "cleaning_crude_new_dataset-" + bash._path_leaf_( path ),
            bash_command= bash.cleaning_dataset( path ),
            dag= dag
        )
        #cleaning_crude_new_dataset.append( temp_task )
        download_crude_new_dataset.set_downstream( temp_task )
```

Comment: get the same result, :(